# Remove Trailing Zeros from a Double Value

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace, double

I have encountered a problem in a solution that I am trying to achieve, namely I need to be able to remove trailing zeros from a double value using `C#`.

For instance, if I were creating two objects that represent a formula, it would be appropriate to say that the two formulas **(2.0 + 7)** and (2.000 + 7) are *equivalent*. That is,  `(2.0 + 7) == (2.00000 + 7)`. However, I'm not sure the best way to approach this is. I'm thinking regular expressions, but I'm not certain that I can get the outcome I am looking for.

It seems that there would be an issue with `resolution` in this case. As an example, the two formulas 2.0 + 7 and 2.000000001 + 7 aren't the same, but they are extremely close. So my question is, could a regular expression account for this? Likewise, would a regular expression be the best approach?

With more elaboration, the following should be legal.

```
Assert.IsTrue(new Formula("2.0 + x7").Equals(new Formula("2.000 + x7")))
```

Within the `Formula` class there is a field that stores reference to a `List` of strings. This list must contain the same value in order for the overridden "Equals" method to return true.

Comment: Which language are you using? And why do you think regex is the task suited for this? Use the appropriate API in the language you are using to format the numbers that way. Like having 1 or 2 decimal places, or so.

Comment: @RohitJain C#. I'm not real comfortable with regular expressions yet, but with the experience that I have, it seems a little non-trivial to ensure resolution while at the same time removing any trailing zeros. I can't just leave the double values to 1 or 2 decimal places because I need to ensure the precision by spec.

Comment: You can use Math.Round(number, decimalplaces)

Comment: No, regexes are not the best approach to check that a float is close to another float. It is better to subtract one number from the other, then verify that the absolute value of this different is smaller than some arbitrary, small value like `0.000001`.

Comment: Are you trying to make a formal language parser or just print numbers out to strings using an approximation ? which keeps the original value untouched of course.

Comment: @v.oddou I need a way of telling if two Strings are within three fractional units of precision.

Comment: Double values in C# have no trailing zeroes and are not represented in any form for which a regex is applicable. The standard response to this kind of question is that you really should go off and read *What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic*, but these days I find [the floating-point guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/) to be a better introduction to the problem.

Comment: @DanielPryden The problem with your approach is that the values are stored as strings, hence the reason why I thought maybe a regular expression was most valid. P.S. I have read that article.

Comment: @Jonathan: if your values are strings, then they aren't doubles. They can't be both at once. I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: @DanielPryden Sorry for the confusion. I have added more detail in my original post. Take a look.

Comment: @Jonathan: so do you have doubles, or do you have strings? Despite the word "double" in your question title, body, and tags, I see no sign that you're actually using doubles anywhere. If you want to do math with strings, there are libraries for that. If you want to do math with doubles, we can help with that too. Can you take a step back and explain *what you're actually trying to do*? You may be facing an [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 3):

You don't need RegExp, just use  [Math.Round(Double, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75ks3aby.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
double num = 587.21500;
var res = Double.Parse(num.ToString("G29"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double variable = 56.123456;
string twoplaces = String.Format("{0:0.##}", variable);
```

?

Comment: This will round the decimals. Try it with `double variable = 56.99911;`